# How to replace a string inside of Json using java

Tags: java

```
[
    "label": {
        "originalName"      : "Case #",
        "modifiedLabel"     : "Case #",
        "labelId"           : "case_number_lbl",
        "isEditable"        : "true",
        "imageClass"        : ""
    }
]
```

In the above Json Array I need to replace "Case #" with "Ticket #". This is occuring in somany places. Any one update please.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: What is the type of the data? Is it `org.json.JSONArray`?

Comment: Yes. My string is JsonObject With JSONArray

Comment: This is not a valid json. If you have an array `[ ... ]` the elements inside do not have names. `"label":` should not be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple loop should solve your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray("[" +
            "    {" +
            "        originalName      : \"Case #\"," +
            "        modifiedLabel     : \"Case #\"," +
            "        labelId           : \"case_number_lbl\"," +
            "        isEditable        : \"true\"," +
            "        imageClass        : \"\"" +
            "    }" +
            "]");

    System.out.println(array.toString(2));

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray keys = object.names();
        for (int j = 0; j < keys.length(); j++) {
            String key = keys.getString(j);
            if (object.getString(key).equals("Case #")) {
                object.put(key, "Ticket #");
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(array.toString(2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GSON to convert your json to java Object and then you can change your string .

Answer (score 1):

You can exchange the value with the help [String.replaceAll()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm)

```
String jSONString = ...; // Your JSon string
String newString = jSONString.replace("Case #", "Ticket #");
```

Comment: Can you explain why you prefer to use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) over [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)?

Comment: Hi Tom, replace is a better match, (I agree). replaceAll uses regex, where replace only uses a CharSequence